# finding if a triangle is ISOSCELES in bash

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, sh

How can this code could be summarized for when the triangle is ISOSCELES?

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 
  3 read x y z
  4 
  5 if [[ x -eq z ]] && [[ x -eq y ]] && [[ y -eq z ]]; then
  6   echo EQUILATERAL
  7 elif [[ x -eq z ]] && [[ x -eq y ]]
  8 then
  9   echo ISOSCELES
 10 elif [[ y -eq z ]] && [[ y -eq x ]]
 11 then
 12   echo ISOSCELES
 13 elif [[ z -eq x ]] && [[ z -eq y ]]
 14 then
 15   echo ISOSCELES
 16 else
 17   echo SCALENE
 18 fi
~
```

currently actually the code doesn't work:

```
$ ./triangle.sh 
4 4 6
SCALENE
$ ./triangle.sh 
4 5 5
SCALENE
$ ./triangle.sh 
4 5 3
SCALENE
$ ./triangle.sh 
4 4 4 
EQUILATERAL
$ ./triangle.sh 
2 9 1
SCALENE
$ ./triangle.sh 
2 3 2
SCALENE
```

Comment: I don't know much about bash, but it's the semi colon supposed to be at the end of the first if?

Comment: @zymus, Yes `;` or new-line delimits this syntax, so both forms as shown here are correct. Good luck to all.

Comment: Consider selecting one answer if it helped you: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

Your code is almost correct, but there is one test more than needed on each case.

In:

```
[[ x -eq y ]] && [[ x -eq z ]] && [[ y -eq z ]]
```

If `x=y` and `x=z` it **must** follow that `y=z`. There is no need for such test.

In:

```
[[ x -eq z ]] && [[ x -eq y ]]
```

If `x=z` there are two sides of equal value, no need for any additional test.

Your script cleaned a little becomes:

```
#!/bin/bash

read x y z

if   [[ x -eq y ]] && [[ x -eq z ]]; then echo EQUILATERAL
elif [[ x -eq y ]]                 ; then echo ISOSCELES
elif [[ x -eq z ]]                 ; then echo ISOSCELES
elif [[ y -eq z ]]                 ; then echo ISOSCELES
else                                      echo SCALENE
fi
```

And furthermore, the three tests for an ISOCELES triangle could be done in one line with OR (`||`):

```
#!/bin/bash

read x y z

if   [[ x -eq y ]] && [[ x -eq z ]]                 ; then echo EQUILATERAL
elif [[ x -eq y ]] || [[ x -eq z ]] || [[ y -eq z ]]; then echo ISOSCELES
else                                                       echo SCALENE
fi
```

Or even (taking advantage of `[[` use):

```
#!/bin/bash

read x y z

if   [[ x -eq y && x -eq z ]]           ; then echo EQUILATERAL
elif [[ x -eq y || x -eq z || y -eq z ]]; then echo ISOSCELES
else                                           echo SCALENE
fi
```

---

Please note that the variable names without a `$` work only in this case of using a `[[` with an arithmetic test `-eq`.
The usual wisdom is to use the correct names for variables, like `[[ $x -eq $y ]]`.

---

To cover the other answer you wrote, here is a corrected script:

- no real need for xplusy variables
- tests could be arithmetic directly
- using arguments instead of read.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

triangle(){
    x=$1 y=$2 z=$3
    for i in $x $y $z; do
        if (( i < 1 ||  i > 1000 )); then
            printf '%4d %4d %4d %s\n' "$x" "$y" "$z" "side out of range"
            return 1
        fi
    done

    if (( ! ( x+y > z && y+z > x && z+x > y )  )); then
        printf '%4d %4d %4d %s\n' "$x" "$y" "$z" "not a triangle"
        return 1
    fi

    if   (( x != z && x != y && y != z )); then printf '%4d %4d %4d %s\n' "$x" "$y" "$z" SCALENE
    elif (( x == y && x == z ))          ; then printf '%4d %4d %4d %s\n' "$x" "$y" "$z" EQUILATERAL
    else                                        printf '%4d %4d %4d %s\n' "$x" "$y" "$z" ISOSCELES
    fi
}

triangle 4    4  6
triangle 4    5  5
triangle 4    5  3
triangle 4    4  4
triangle 2    9  1
triangle 2    3  2
triangle 100  3  3
triangle 1    2  1000
triangle 1003 3  3
```

When executed, the script will print:

```
./script.sh
   4    4    6 ISOSCELES
   4    5    5 ISOSCELES
   4    5    3 SCALENE
   4    4    4 EQUILATERAL
   2    9    1 not a triangle
   2    3    2 ISOSCELES
 100    3    3 not a triangle
   1    2 1000 not a triangle
1003    3    3 side out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

**A short and simple way**

```
case $(cat - | uniq -u | wc -l) in
0) echo "EQUILATERAL";; 1) echo "ISOSCELES";; 3) echo "SCALENE"
esac
```

**uniq -u**

> To only show lines that are not repeated pass the -u option to uniq. This will output only lines that are not repeated and write the result to standard output.

**wc -l**

> returns line count

*Example: For 2 3 4,
**uniq -u** will return 3 and hence **wc -l** will return 3.*

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my code to below and it works but I still would like to know why above code didn't work in the given tests:

```
 1 #!/bin/bash
  2 
  3 read x y z
  4 
  5 if [[ x -ne z ]] && [[ x -ne y ]] && [[ y -ne z ]]; then
  6   echo SCALENE
  7 elif [[ x -eq z ]] && [[ x -eq y ]] && [[ y -eq z ]]; then
  8   echo EQUILATERAL
  9 else
 10   echo ISOSCELES
 11 fi
```

Here's a more complete version of the code with checking to see if it is a triangle and also checking to see if each side is between 1 and 1000.

```
1 #!/bin/bash
  2 
  3 read x y z
  4 #for i in x y z
  5 #do
  6 #  (( i >= 1 )) && (( i <= 1000 )) || echo error
  7 #done
  8 xplusy=$x+$y
  9 yplusz=$y+$z
 10 zplusx=$z+$x
 11 if [[ $x -ge 1 ]] && [[ $x -le 1000 ]] &&
 12    [[ $y -ge 1 ]] && [[ $y -le 1000 ]] &&
 13    [[ $z -ge 1 ]] && [[ $z -le 1000 ]]; then
 14 if [[ $xplusy -gt $z ]] && [[ $yplusz -gt $x ]] && [[ $zplusx -gt $y ]]; then
 15 if [[ $x -ne $z ]] && [[ $x -ne $y ]] && [[ $y -ne $z ]]; then
 16   echo SCALENE
 17 elif [[ $x -eq $z ]] && [[ $x -eq $y ]] && [[ $y -eq $z ]]; then
 18   echo EQUILATERAL
 19 else
 20   echo ISOSCELES
 21 fi
 22 fi
 23 fi
```

Comment: I am looking for more responses mostly working on what is wrong in the question.

Comment: You sorted out that `[[ $x -eq $z ]] && [[ $x -eq $y ]]` also means `[[ $y -eq $z ]]` (*associative property of equality*), thus equilateral. (note the `'$'` before each variable name).

Comment: Your code breaks on an input like 100 3 3, reporting that as ISOSCELES, and 1 2 1000 as SCALENE. These are impossible triangles!!! Always think about bad inputs, not only the valid ones. "What will people do to try to break my program?"

Comment: @Kaz - it's generally called `GiGo`. And you are absolutely right. Inputs must be verified to not contain garbage.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  why the code works with $x or x in [[ ]] ? I am a little confused

Comment: @Kaz fixed the code please have a look and thanks for feedback

Comment: @MonaJalal - You are correct, `((` and `[[` allow dereference without the explicit `$` (as does the normal indexed array syntax on the index variable, e.g. `${array[i]}`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I think only arithmetic expansion `(( ))` allows to skip the `$`.

Comment: in my case [[ ]] allowed to skip $ @BenjaminW.

Comment: @MonaJalal Can you show me an example where you could skip the `$`?

Comment: Since `-eq` is an integer operator, `bash` applies the same lookup logic to attempted string operands as it does inside an arithmetic context. That is, `-eq` creates an arithmetic context inside `[[ ... ]]`. (The same is not true for `[ x -eq y ]` because `[` is a normal command, without the same special argument handling available to `[[...]]`.)

Comment: @BenjaminW. line 7 of my answer `7 elif [[ x -eq z ]] && [[ x -eq y ]] && [[ y -eq z ]]; then`

Comment: @chepner I just realized that in my own little tests - learned something!

Comment: @BenjaminW. It struct me as funny too, that prompted my first comment. Then testing, as you did, with the integer comparison it worked just fine... So much for consistency in all things bash... Added one more caveat to the lid of the bash toolbox..

Comment: Checking that the sides are less than 1000 is not what I had in mind at all.  2000 2000 2000 is a valid equilateral triangle. What my comment means is that the triangle 1 2 1000 is impossible; if you have sticks of that length, you cannot make a triangle. This is because 1 + 2 < 1000.    The condition is that x + y > z && x + z > y && y  + z > x.  If this condition isn't true, the three numbers cannot specify the lengths of the edges of a triangle.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The one other place I was aware of this outside of `(( ))` (and ignoring any `declare -i` cases) was the index of an array: `arr=(0 1 2 3); x=2; echo ${arr[x]}` dereferences the `x`.

Comment: @Kaz I am solving a challenge from hackerrank and that was the requirement. I know that is also a triangle!

Comment: On line 17 there is no need for the third test `[[ $y -eq $z ]]`.

Comment: @MonaJalal The indenting of your code is confusing, and please remove the leading line numbers, it is not usual to have them. Otherwise, keep solving problems, that is the way to really learn.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the relevant code to help with your issue.

```
#!/bin/bash

read x;
read y;
read z;
if [ $x -eq $y ] && [ $y -eq $z ]
then
echo "EQUILATERAL"
elif [ $x -ne $y ] && [ $x -ne $z ] && [ $y -ne $z ]
then
echo "SCALENE"
else
echo "ISOSCELES"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
read x
read y
read z

if [[ $x -eq $y ]] && [[ $y -eq $z ]]; then
  echo EQUILATERAL
elif [[ $x != $y ]] && [[ $y != $z ]] && [[ $x != $z ]]; then
  echo SCALENE
else
    echo ISOSCELES
fi
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: It is also functionality equivalent to https://stackoverflow.com/a/65204554/1364007. Duplicate answers should not be posted and will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

read a
read b
read c
if [ $a == $b ] && [ $a == $c ] && [ $b == $c ]
then
echo "EQUILATERAL"
elif [ $a == $b ]
then
echo "ISOSCELES"
elif [ $c == $a ]
then
echo "ISOSCELES"
elif [ $b == $c ]
then
echo "ISOSCELES"
else
echo "SCALENE"
fi

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my code to below and it works:

```
read X
read Y
read Z

if (("$X","$Y","$Z" > "1000")) || (("$X","$Y","$Z" < "1"));then
  exit

else
  if (("$X"=="$Y")) && (("$Y"=="$Z")) && (("$X"=="$Z"));then
    echo "EQUILATERAL"
  elif  (("$X"=="$Y")) || (("$Y"=="$Z")) || (("$X"=="$Z"));then
    echo "ISOSCELES"
  else
    echo "SCALENE"
  fi
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

```
read x 
read y 
read z
if [[ x -ne z ]] && [[ x -ne y ]] && [[ y -ne z ]]; then
echo "SCALENE"
elif [[ x -ne z ]]
then
echo "ISOSCELES"
elif [[ y -ne z ]]
then
echo "ISOSCELES"
elif [[ z -ne x ]]
then
echo "ISOSCELES"
else
echo "EQUILATERAL"
fi
```

This is what worked out for me.

Answer (score -3):

This is untested, but here's the general idea:

```
#!/bin/bash

read x y z

if [ $x -eq $z ] && [ $x -eq $y ]; then
  # You can't test x==y==z directly, so do it in two parts
  echo EQUILATERAL
elif [ $x -eq $z ] || [ $x -eq $y ] || [ $y -eq $z ]; then
    # isosceles == any pair of sides are the same
    echo ISOSCELES
else
    echo SCALENE
fi
```

As for the "what's wrong in the original question"... let's just take one of the supposed to be iscosceles tests `elif [[ x -eq z ]] && [[ x -eq y ]]` you can see how to satisfy this all three sides must be equal. Similar problems with all of the checks.